# How to parse a string in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I need to parse a sentence. 
If I find a hash in the sentence, I would like to bold it.

Example : Bonjour `#hello` Hi => Bonjour **#hello** Hi

Comment: Probably belongs on StackOverflow, and post what code you've tried along with the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a good situation for regex

I'd do something like this

```
boldHashes("Bonjour #hello Hi");

...

private string boldHashes(string str)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, @"(#\w+)", "<strong>$1</strong>");
}
```

In this case we're matching a literal hash `#` plus a word of any length `\w+` and group it between `()` so we can use the `$1` [substitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) in the [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) function

---

**Updated** jQuery doing the same thing.

Something like:

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">Bonjour #Hello hi</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#myDiv').html($('#myDiv').text().replace(/(#\w+)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>'));
```

Comment: Is it possible to use it in the view ? Because I need it in the html. Because I want to save this string without `<strong></strong>`

Comment: How to do the same thing with jQuery ? please ?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this but you can use the [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx) method to find the first instance of the hash like so

```
String myString = "Bonjour #hello hi";
int index = myString.IndexOf('#');
if(index>-1) //IndexOf returns -1 if the character isn't found
{
  //search for the next space after the hash
  int endIndex=mystring.IndexOf(' ',index+1)
  myString=MakeBold(myString,index,endIndex);
}
```

All that's left for you is to implement the MakeBold function.

Comment: also, you probably want to extend the function to take into account multiple hashes in the string.